# Using a custom BottomSheetDialog class means I can't touchOutside to cancel

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

So I made a custom class that does basically nothing except boilerplate code plus customizing the callback. For whatever reason, I can't seem to make it cancel when I touch outside the bounds of the bottom sheet.

```
public class CustomBottomSheetDialog extends AppCompatDialog {

public CustomBottomSheetDialog(Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.Theme_Design_Light_BottomSheetDialog);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View view) {
    final CoordinatorLayout coordinator = (CoordinatorLayout) View.inflate(getContext(),
            R.layout.design_bottom_sheet_dialog, null);
    FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) coordinator.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
    BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetCallback);
    bottomSheet.addView(view);
    super.setContentView(coordinator);
}

private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback mBottomSheetCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStateChanged(View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
            cancel(); // The only not boilerplate code here, woo
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSlide(View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) { }
};
```

Things I've tried:

bottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(true);
bottomSheetDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
Overriding dispatchTouchEvent, but I can't get the rectangle to equal anything besides the size of the entire screen.
If I don't use the custom class (ie simply change my CustomBottomSheetDialog call to just BottomSheetDialog), I get the cancel on touch outside, but then I don't get a cancel when I drag to hide the dialog, which I am required to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it. In the onCreate, I added a single line of code to find the touch_outside view and add a click listener to cancel the dialog. The touch_outside view is generated by default. I did not need to add it in my bottom sheet's XML.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    findViewById(R.id.touch_outside).setOnClickListener(v -> cancel()); // <--- this guy
    getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
}
```

Thanks goes to [this tutorial](http://www.hidroh.com/2016/06/17/bottom-sheet-everything/).